# My touchpad freezes

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, focaltech

I have a problem with the arrow pointer of my Asus Zenbook UX303LN-R4203H 64 bits under Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS (dual boot W8) which has been freezing continuously for the last 2 months. I can only work with an external mouse. Under Windows 8 I have no problem as the touchpad works perfectly. I am French, a total beginner with Linux and don't master well the English IT language.

Whenever I update, a window opens and says:

> Problem in focaltech-dkms.The problem cannot be reported. This pack is not officially supported by Ubuntu. Uninstall any third-party pack and try again.

In case this may be of help, here is the output of **dmesg | grep pnp**:

```
[ 0.245400] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[ 0.245827] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[ 0.246060] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0101 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[ 0.246106] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[ 0.247172] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a Focaltech touchpad that is fully supported by Ubuntu since kernel 4.2. You can fix it by upgrading the kernel.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

and reboot.

If you previously installed `focaltech-dkms`, you should remove it first by running

```
sudo apt-get purge focaltech-dkms
```

That is a ppa package that I created to add support of Focaltech touchpads for kernels 3.19.x. It is not needed any more.

Comment: I did exactly as suggested (both runs) but the problem is not solved, I am afraid, as the pointer still freezes